# How to try and display users that do no have entries for latest week in database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Good day,

i have a table with user activity information in.

the table basically is as follow:

```
Eventdate,     UserId,       Activity
2013-09-09     SusanM        Support Call
2013-09-09     BrandonP      Meeting
2013-09-09     MumbaM        Administration
2013-09-16     SusanM        Support Call
2013-09-16     BrandonP      Meeting
```

so as you can see everyone has updated there work for the 9th, but user MumbaM has not yet logged his entry for the 16th.
is it possible to show on report if i select the date for the 16th MumbaM, even if he has no entry in the database? is there a way to right an sql query to based on the previous userid entries to include Mumbam for the 16th.

So I would like the report for the 16th to display as follow:

```
2013-09-16     SusanM        Support Call
2013-09-16     BrandonP      Meeting
2013-09-16     MumbaM        no update yet
```

Comment: if you have a table to store every userID then this will be very easy..
do you have such table in your database?

Comment: Do you have a separate table for the user names? Or do you just want a list of all users that have at least one entry in your user_activity table?

Comment: we do have a table that stores each userID, but no dates

Comment: I need to show the entries weekly for all users, but also for the users that have not updated there work, so there will be no entries in the activity table for them yet

Comment: apologies, i am using microsoft sql 2012

Comment: @user1854183: I corrected my answer, this one whould work. Let me know.

Comment: @AndreaCarrer: the union was the way to go, after a bit of tweak on our side we managed to display exactly what was needed. thanks

Comment: @user1854183: Happy to hear it! Remember to vote up and confirm the answer, if you feel it was useful. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT t1.Eventdate, t1.UserId, t1.Activity
FROM YourTable t1
WHERE t1.Eventdate = '2013-09-16'

UNION

SELECT t1.Eventdate, t1.UserId, 'No update yet' as Activity
FROM YourTable t1
WHERE t1.userid not in (SELECT UserId FROM YourTable WHERE Eventdate = '2013-09-16')
    AND t1.Eventdate = 
        (SELECT TOP 1 t3.Eventdate FROM YourTable as t3 WHERE t3.UserID = t1.UserId)
GROUP BY t1.UserID, t1.Eventdate
ORDER BY Eventdate DESC
```

Comment: Note: With the 2dn query I select the most recent activity of users who don't have an activity in the given date.

Comment: i have tried this, thank you so much, it does take a very long time to run though

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this but instead of 'no update yet', you'll get NULL;

```
SELECT t1.Eventdate, t1.UserId, t2.Activity
From Table t1
Left Outer Join Table t2
on t1.UserId = t2.UserId
Where Eventdate = '2013/09/16'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use decode or case, rather than joining:

```
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE),
       userid,
       CASE TRUNC (eventdate)
          WHEN TRUNC (SYSDATE) THEN Activity
          ELSE 'no update yet'
       END
  FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two tables 'Activity' and 'User' as follows:

**User**

```
Id,   UserId
1     SusanM
2     BrandonP
3     MumbaM
4     SusanM
5     BrandonP
```

**Activity**

```
Eventdate,     UserId,       Activity
2013-09-09     SusanM        Support Call
2013-09-09     BrandonP      Meeting
2013-09-09     MumbaM        Administration
2013-09-16     SusanM        Support Call
2013-09-16     BrandonP      Meeting
```

The following query will give you the result you want:

```
select 
    u.UserId, NVL(a.Activity, 'no update yet') as Activity 
from 
    user u 
left outer join 
    activity a 
on 
    a.UserId=u.UserId 
where 
    a.Eventdate=sysdate
```